# xslt transform error: XTSE0010: Element xsl:mode must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, saxon

I'm looking to change nodes from one value to another.  Not the value of the node, but the name of the node.  Not the content inside the tags.

Wikipedia would say "tags" as:

> Tag
>       A tag is a markup construct that begins with < and ends with >. Tags come in three flavors:
>
> ```
>     start-tag, such as <section>;
>     end-tag, such as </section>;
>     empty-element tag, such as <line-break />.
> ```

**So I'm looking to rename all of the above tags of one name to another.  As `foo` to `bar` or `bar` to `baz`, etc.**

running `saxonb-xslt` returns:

```
Saxon 9.1.0.8J from Saxonica
```

Perhaps this version of `Saxon` doesn't have capabilities, or, more likely, the `xslt` is flawed.

truncated `xml` from a larger file:

```
<csv>
  <foo>
    <entry>Reported_Date</entry>
    <entry>HA</entry>
    <entry>Sex</entry>
    <entry>Age_Group</entry>
    <entry>Classification_Reported</entry>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <entry>2020-01-26</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </bar>
  <record>
    <baz>2020-02-02</baz>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>baz</entry>
    <entry>50-59</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>20-29</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
</csv>
```

the `xslt` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <baz><xsl:apply-templates/></baz>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

error:

```
Error at xsl:mode on line 9 column 41 of bc.rename.xslt:
  XTSE0010: Element xsl:mode must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet
Error at xsl:mode on line 9 column 41 of bc.rename.xslt:
  XTSE0010: Unknown XSLT element: mode
Failed to compile stylesheet. 2 errors detected.
```

Both the `xml` document and the `xslt` document pass `xmllint` with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:mode` requires XSLT 3.0. AFAIK, Saxon 9.1 only supports XSLT 2.0.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <baz>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </baz>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Correct, Saxon 9.1 dates from 2009, long before XSLT 3.0 was invented. The current version is Saxon 10.1; there have been about 50 major and minor releases in between.